# Hostname “N/A” on one network while on the other one is defined correctly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a RaspberryPi 3B+ device which I tried connecting to two different networks. To the first network I connected with a cable (eth0). Once I scan the network for the devices, I can clearly see my Pi device there.
[image]

On the other hand, while I connect to a different network over Wifi (wlan0), I cannot see the hostname of my Pi device. I see that it's there, but it has no hostname.

[image]

What could be the cause that on one network I can see the hostname, and on another one I can't?

Comment: Maybe no name server. Maybe broadcasts are disabled. Maybe ... a lot of reasons.

Comment: @Akina But the problem is definitely not comming from the Pi device? It's high likely related to the router settings?